# navigation intent for opening multiple options (Google Maps, Waze, Uber) and omit the non working applications

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem to write a proper intent which results in multiple options to get navigation for one specific point. As a starting point i used the [google website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents).

`String uri = "google.navigation:q=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;`

<- this uri is working for *Google maps*. *Waze* does not have the destination, so does not work. *Uber* does not have the destination, so does not work.

`String uri = "geo:" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;`

<- *Waze* is working. *Uber* is working. *Google Maps* does not have the destination, so does not work. And also have there some application which does not navigate, just show the location on the map what I do not want to be presented.

tried to combine the two approaches like this :
`String uri = "geo:" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude+"?q=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;`

<- *Waze* is working. The *Uber* is working. The *Google Maps* is working nearly ok, does not start the navigation but it is ok. But also have there some application which does not navigate, just show the location on the map what I do not want to be presented.

So to summarize is there a way to have just a couple of application presented as an navigation option, and if so can I verify somehow if they are ok with the given uri?